# Angular5:compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync not working with AoT

Tags: angular5, angular2-aot

I am working on a project wherein I need to use --prod flag to build the angular code.
In one of our module there is a component which is being created at run-time.
The project works fine when build with dev environment.
But when --prod flag is used the project gets build successfully but throws a run-time exception at methos 'compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync()'.
I have googled a lot for this but didn't find any promising solution. Can anybody help me in this?

Excepton Details:

```
main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
at fe (main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1)
at e.compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync (main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1)
at e.addComponent (main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1)
at e.onSubmit (main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1)
at Object.handleEvent (main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1)
at Object.handleEvent (main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1)
at Object.handleEvent (main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1)
at cn (main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1)
at main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1)@ main.0c80be8a6ff7c0136620.bundle.js:1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JIT compiler is generally not available from AoT mode, here is a workaround taken from [Angular's integration example](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d7a727cc0728a61a707f2c109636c1fa077042c2/integration/dynamic-compiler/src/app.module.ts#L16).

```
import {Compiler, COMPILER_OPTIONS, CompilerFactory, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {JitCompilerFactory} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {provide: COMPILER_OPTIONS, useValue: {}, multi: true},
    {provide: CompilerFactory, useClass: JitCompilerFactory, deps: [COMPILER_OPTIONS]},
    {provide: Compiler, useFactory: createCompiler, deps: [CompilerFactory]}
  ]
})
```

There is also an [open feature request](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20875) to include jit compiler in AoT mode.